Function for listing processes holding a specified file open
The function's prototype is:
int processes_using(const char *name, pid_t pidlist[], int size)

It searches through all processes it can to find any that have an open file descriptor against the file specified by name. It writes the list of PIDs that hold the file open to the array pidlist[] which must be allocated by the caller to size elements. The function returns the number of PIDs that it has placed in the array or -1 on error. Contents of the array at indices greater than the function's return result minus one are undefined (eg if it returns 7, then only up to pidlist[6] is defined).
The function considers a process to be holding the file open if its inode and device number matches that of one of the files that the process has open.
Limitations (intentional):

Only works for regular files (ie S_ISREG(st_mode) == true)

Does not search for multiple files simultaneously

The caller must allocate the buffer and come up with a reasonable size


I would like to know if there is any way to make this function simpler while retaining identical functionality (even if the prototype has to change), whether there are any subtle problems in the assumptions in the code (eg if the symlinks in /proc/<pid>/fd/ could be non-numerical in some obscure situation), and whether there are any glaring stylistic concerns (not involving line limits, which I set to 120).
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define ERR_LINE(err, fmt, ...) error_at_line(0, err, __FILE__, __LINE__, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)

static inline bool is_all_digits(const char *s)
{
    const unsigned char *c = (unsigned char *)s;

    while (isdigit(*c))
        c++;

    return *c == '\0';
}

int processes_using(const char *name, pid_t pidlist[], int size)
{
    struct stat sb;
    struct dirent *proc_dent;
    DIR *proc_dp, *fd_dp;
    pid_t our_pid;
    int num_open = 0;

    assert(name && pidlist && size > 0);

    if (stat(name, &sb) == -1) {
        ERR_LINE(errno, "stat (%s)", name);
        return -1;
    }

    proc_dp = opendir("/proc");
    if (!proc_dp) {
        ERR_LINE(errno, "opendir");
        return -1;
    }

    our_pid = getpid();

    /* walk through proc entries */
    while ((proc_dent = readdir(proc_dp))) {
        struct dirent *fd_dent;
        char fd_dir[PATH_MAX];
        pid_t this_pid;

        /* not a pid directory? */
        if (proc_dent->d_type != DT_DIR || !is_all_digits(proc_dent->d_name))
            continue;

        this_pid = (pid_t)atol(proc_dent->d_name);

        /* our own pid directory? */
        if (our_pid == this_pid)
            continue;

        snprintf(fd_dir, PATH_MAX, "/proc/%s/fd", proc_dent->d_name);

        /* open the fd directory in the pid directory */
        fd_dp = opendir(fd_dir);
        if (!fd_dp) {
            if (errno == ENOENT || errno == EACCES)
                continue;

            ERR_LINE(errno, "opendir (%s)", fd_dir);
            goto err_out;
        }

        /* iterate through fd symlinks */
        while ((fd_dent = readdir(fd_dp))) {
            struct stat fd_sb;

            if (!strcmp(fd_dent->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(fd_dent->d_name, ".."))
                continue;

            assert(fd_dent->d_type == DT_LNK && is_all_digits(fd_dent->d_name));

            /* get this fd's stat */
            if (fstatat(dirfd(fd_dp), fd_dent->d_name, &fd_sb, 0) == -1) {
                ERR_LINE(errno, "fstatat (%s)", fd_dent->d_name);
                goto err_out_fd_dp;
            }

            /* compare target stat with this fd's stat */
            if (S_ISREG(fd_sb.st_mode) && fd_sb.st_dev == sb.st_dev && fd_sb.st_ino == sb.st_ino) {
                if (num_open + 1 > size) {
                    ERR_LINE(0, "buffer too small");
                    goto err_out_fd_dp;
                }

                pidlist[num_open++] = this_pid;
            }
        }

        closedir(fd_dp);
    }

    closedir(proc_dp);
    return num_open;

err_out_fd_dp:
    closedir(fd_dp);
err_out:
    closedir(proc_dp);
    return -1;
}

A sample program (quick and dirty, not part of the review) showing how it can be used:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int processes_using(const char *, pid_t [], int);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t pidlist[256];
    int nfound;

    if (argc != 2)
        return 1;

    nfound = processes_using(argv[1], pidlist, 256);
    if (nfound == -1)
        return 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < nfound; i++)
        printf("%d\n", pidlist[i]);

    return 0;
}


Apparently you assume the existence of a /proc filesystem – is this for Linux only? – In that case I suggest to add the [linux] tag.

Is pid_t specified to not be wider than int in Linux?  Without that spec, printf("%d\n", pidlist[i]); risks UB.  printf("%jd\n", (intmax_t) pidlist[i]); avoids that risk.

Do you really want is_all_digits("") to return true?

Avoid having to build path names
You avoided building some path names by using fstatat(). But you still are building fd_dir. You can avoid that by using fdopendir(proc_dp, proc_dent->d_name), and from that one again use fdopendir() to go into the subdirectory fd/.
Just check if entries in fd/ are symlinks
Instead of checking the filename, some of which is done in an assert() that might be compiled out, just always check if fd_end->d_type == DT_LNK, and then compare the "stats". Note that "." and ".." are not symlinks.
Consider using statx()
stat() and friends return a lot of metadata for a file. That data has to be retrieved from somewhere, and depending on the filesystem, that might take some time. You could use statx(…, STATX_INO) instead, which might be more efficient.
Use size_t
Always prefer to use size_t for sizes, counts and indices. It is guaranteed to be large enough to address anything that can fit into memory, whereas int might not and more easily overflows. If you need signed numbers, then you can use ssize_t.
Defer calling atol()
You can defer checking if our_pid == this_pid (if it's needed at all), and then you can defer calling atol() to when you have actually found a match.
Split the function up into multiple helper functions
The function process_using() is a bit long, and has several levels of nesting that is both the cause of those long lines, as well as needing multiple goto labels. By splitting this function up you can address these issues and make the code more readable. It should look like:
static void check_fd(struct dirent *fd_dent, int *num_open, …) {
    …
    if (!S_ISREG(fd_sb.st_mode))
        return;

    if (fd_sb.st_dev != sb.st_dev || fd_sb.st_ino != sb.st_ino)
        return;
       
    pidlist[(*num_open)++] = this_pid;
}

static void check_process(struct dirent *proc_dent, int *num_open, …) {
    …
    while ((fd_dent = readdir(fd_dp)))
        check_fd(fd_ent, num_open, …);
    …
}

int processes_using(const char *name, pid_t pidlist[], int size) {
    …
    while ((proc_dent = readdir(proc_dp)))
        check_process(proc_dent, &num_open, …);
    …
}

If you need to pass a lot of parameters to each function, consider creating a struct to group them together, and then just pass a pointer to that struct.
Error handling
I see you are checking the return values of most functions to see if they return an error. That's great! I also see that you don't consider ENOENT and EACCESS a problem, which is great since a process could exit between a call to readdir(proc_dp) and a subsequent opendir(fd_dir). However, also consider that a process could close a file descriptor at any time, so if fstatat() fails, don't consider that a fatal error, and just continue instead.
Be aware of TOCTTOU issues
While your function is doing the best it can, there is a time-of-check to time-of-use (TOCTTOU) issue here. Not only can processes appear and disappear while you are processing the /proc directory, it can even happen (although it is very unlikely) that one process that indeed had the given file open quits, and then another process that doesn't use the file starts and gets the same PID.
Between the caller calling process_using() and process_using() statting name to get its inode, that file could have been renamed and no longer being what the caller thought it was. If the caller already has opened the file somehow, then consider creating a version of process_using() that takes a filedescriptor instead of a string as input, and then use fstat() on it to get the inode.
Last but not least, POSIX requires that inodes are unique for a given filesystem, but not all filesystems are POSIX compliant.
